# Use function type group

Tags: go, types

I'd like to use function types and group some of them together (usually to pass them to other funcs).

```
type bla func()
type bla2 func(string)

/* this one doesn't compile...
type blaer interface {
    bla
    bla2
}
*/

// this one compiles
type blaS struct {
    bla
    bla2
}

func main() {
    s := blaS{
        bla : func(){fmt.Println("Hello, playground")},
        bla2 : func(s string){fmt.Println("Hello, ", s)},
    }
    s.bla() 
    s.bla2("world")
}
```

Is there a way to use them in interfaces ?
Otherwise, do you know any drawback with using structs instead of interfaces ?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax:

```
type blaer interface {
    bla
    bla2
}
```

is declaring an interface with two member variables, not methods. You cannot declare variables in an interface.

When you use a function type in a struct like this:

```
type blaS struct {
    bla
    bla2
}
```

what you're doing is defining a struct with two member variables, one named `bla` of type `bla`, and another named `bla2` of type `bla2`. You can use `s.bla()` and `s.bla2()` however, that doesn't mean `s` implements the hypothetical interface `blaer` containing the `bla` and `bla2` methods. Because the two function pointers are not methods of type `blaS`, `s` does not implement the interface.

So the exact answer depends on your use case. If you need to use interfaces, you have to define the two functions as methods. If you need function pointers that you can set, you have to use structs.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer.
In fact, the real problem I have is that I can't even declare the interface. 
The way it's implemented or that the struct is instantiated is a detail, actually.

```
type bla func()
type bla2 func(string)

/* this one doesn't compile...
type blaer interface {
    bla
    bla2
}
```
I don't know why it doesn't work, maybe there's a special syntax I don't know...

Comment: Because with the syntax you declared the interface, you're declaring member variables, not functions. And you cannot declare variables in an interface. See the modified answer